# How to give my Flutter App access to macOS web cam and microphone?

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-desktop

I have a Flutter app that runs on iPad. It uses Agora for video calling. I need to create a desktop version but I cannot find anywhere how to access macbook's web cam and microphone for the video call. I am using the PermissionHandler package for iPad but it does not support macOS. I tried Github issues and stackoverflow but I havent been able to find anything. Is there no way to access the web cam/microphone for desktop as of yet? If there is, please help me find it.